# Volt Framework integration test with Phantom not populating page with objects in store

Tags: phantomjs, capybara, voltrb

I'm having a page show a list of objects (*for example, some todos in a todo list*), and the list does not successfully get populated in integration tests with `phantom`.

Feature works in a regular browser, and I can verify I'm successfully populating the database for the test, but nothing shows up when I use `Capybara` to verify that they're on the page. They don't appear on the page in the `phantom` browser at all, as far as I can tell (*fiddled around with `byebug` to be sure*).

`Volt` is version 0.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of volt that I need to fix.  Currently integration tests don't sync between the_page in the spec and page on the client side.  (store works fine if that helps)  Hopefully I can get some time soon to make this work.  (Or if anyone wants to help me, hit me up in gitter)

Comment: To clarify, you mean ```store``` works fine to store objects, but not to propagate them to the page? Or that the tests should function and pass if they're all dealing with objects in the ```store``` collection, even when those objects are their html representations on the page? The list I'm dealing with for this is all in ```store```, although filtered with a search term that is in the ```page``` collection. Not sure what that means the implications are?

Comment: store should propagate.